# cooked corned beef, "potted meats". preservation

Tags: food-preservation

I cooked corned beef that is to be used as sandwiches or tortilla wraps, so 
I chilled my freshly corned beef in a Ziplock bag  and was thinking about the method of "potting meats" for preservation.
So, what if I left the sliced corned beef in the "jelly" from cooking, (I make my own bonebroths. Hence, the jelly from the corned beef.lard), and topped it off with the fat from the same cooking liquid or, some fresh rendered lard?

Would this work to truly preserve my corned beef? It's coloring, texture, and taste?
(I steam my corned beef, and other meats, to reheat them, or wrap them in foil and heat them to the correct temperature.)

Comment: When you say "preserve" -- Under what conditions (refrigeration, freezer, higher temperature, etc.)? How long?  If I remember correctly, traditional "potted meats" were generally stored *in* fat, with a fat layer on top, but it seems you want to put your meat within *gelled* stock, then fat on top?  Anyhow, I personally wouldn't do this for very long unless it was frozen.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, meats preserved in this fashion were cooked with lots of fat, then the entire dish was cooled quickly to allow the fat to rise to the top and solidify, creating a seal that kept out pathogens.  The entire dish, pot and all were then buried in a hole in the yard.

Although it is certainly possible to do something similar today, I would recommend instead following modern food preparation practices.  Cook in small batches that are cooled in the fridge (small batches to allow the dish to chill quickly and not overwhelming the fridge's cooling ability).  Then keep the dish in the fridge.

In the end, this means keeping the dish in the fridge and not in a hole in the yard, which in my mind takes away a lot of the appeal of this method.  However, modern practice helps prevent food poisoning, so there's that.